# Apply recorded Macro to all Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 21 sheets. 19 of the sheets have Pivot Tables with a date filter. I recorded a macro to allow me to update the filter faster. I was wondering if there was a way for me to edit the code in Visual Basic that would allow me to apply the macro to the 19 sheets with pivot tables when run.

```
Sub WeekUpdate()
'
' WeekUpdate Macro
' Update the week for Wait Vs Price
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2016012]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2017012]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
        "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `For Each` to loop through all the `Worksheets` in the `ActiveWorkBook`.

```
Sub WeekUpdate()
' WeekUpdate Macro
' Update the week for Wait Vs Price
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook

ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2016012]")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2017012]")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
    "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Arguably the two pivot tables should be pulled into their own local objects too - I doubt two worksheets have same-name pivot tables though; this provides a nice starting point, but will definitely blow up with some *index out of bounds* error at one point.